# Restore mongodb data if collection or database was dropped

Tags: mongodb

I need to know - Is it any possibility  to restore data in collection or database if it was dropped?

Comment: I suppose you could use a deleted file recovery program to view deleted files on the disk and restore them but otherwise no, espeically if those sectors have since been overwritten

Answer (score 1):

The OS, by default (or in the case of Windows: any case) will not allow you to restore deleted data. You will need a third party program which can read the sectors. It is also good to note that while database drops will delete the files collection drops will not, instead they get `nulled`.

Dropping a collection should make it near on impossible to retrieve the data since the hard drive sectors that were used have now been overwritten with new data (basically one pass `0`).

So the files *may* be recoverable on a database drop but that is still questionable.